# Losing partition on sd card

Tags: sd-card, partitions, link2sd

I have a 2GB sd card that I have partitioned with minitool partition wizard, Easus partition master and Gparted. Each time I create a 1.5GB fat16 partition set as primary and a 370MB ext2 partition set as primary. I do not have card reader capability so I do it through the phone connected by USB. I use windows 7 to verify that it sees the fat partition and can even copy files to it. I reboot my Samsung Admire (Metro) and it comes up saying the SD card is damaged. You may have to reformat. The phone reformats the card and its back to a single 1.86GB partition again.

I have done this about three times in the past and never had a problem. I got one of my old 2GB sd cards that was already partitioned and it showed the ext partition in Link2SD. Thought I was home free until I copied my backup files to the sd card and poof it was back to a single partition again.

I spent many hours and am out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Comment: When you have your device reformat the card, it overwrites your partitions. Are you trying to get your device to get access to a specific partition?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to partition my sd card so that my rooted Samsung admire could access the Ext2 partition. I am using Link2SD to resolve my low internal memory issue.  I bought a card reader and used Minitool to delete all partitions and rebuild them per my first post.  For some reason it works using the card reader, but not using the phone connected by USB, even though I've done it 3 times that way with my family members phones (all Samsung Admire).

John thanks for your reply

Comment: If this answers your question then you can select it as an answer.